# Unable to get value of radio button in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these radio buttons but I can't get value from those on submit. I tried this exactly the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/4lvJclZuh0lryF1nhmdt?p=preview

HTML:

```
        <body ng-controller="ExamCtrl">
           <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="1"/> One</label>
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="2"/> Two</label>
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="3"/> Three</label>
             <div>currently selected: {{radioValue}}</div>
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
           </form>
        </body>
```

JS:

```
   $scope.submitForm = function () {
       console.log('Submitting');
       console.log($scope.radioValue);
   };
```

It logs 'Submitting' and then `undefined`.

Comment: have you tried your plnkr ???

Comment: You should initialize `$scope.radioValue;` in controller at start of.

Comment: @NiRmaL then it just logs the initialized value.

Comment: Did you logged value like in your HTML snippet and Is it showing different value? When you select different radio button.

Comment: @NiRmaL In HTML, the expression `{{radioValue}}` changes and displays whichever value is clicked.

Comment: Try something like initialize obj `$scope.data = {}` and then ng-model in radio button like `data.radioValue` then you will get value in `$scope.submitForm` as `$scope.data.radioValue`.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't there a better and simpler way to do this?

Comment: So it is working for you. Right? Don't know the exact issue. Angular js detect changes in array and object more high then others. So it is always better to use form input data as in object.

Comment: @NiRmaL Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Check your console you might getting some injection error.

Comment: @NiRmaL yes something similar worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when I use the dot '.' notation. No idea why.

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="ExamCtrl">
   <form name="myForm">
     <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radio.value" value="1"/> One</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radio.value" value="2"/> Two</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radio.alue" value="3"/> Three</label>
     <div>currently selected: {{radioValue}}</div>
     <button ng-click="submitAnswer(radio.value)">Submit</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

JS

```
$scope.submitAnswer = function (selected) {
  // $scope.answer = 'A';
  console.log('submitting');        
  console.log(selected);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is working fine :**

**Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/2scu8wL8/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
   $scope.submitForm = function () {
       console.log('Submitting');
       console.log($scope.radioValue);
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
           <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="1"/> One</label>
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="2"/> Two</label>
             <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="3"/> Three</label>
             <div>currently selected: {{radioValue}}</div>
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
           </form> 
</div>
```